# issue with char arrays indexing

Tags: c, arrays, string

### Motivation

So I have read quite a bit that in C strings are just char arrays which are just char pointers.

I'm guessing what I have read is either wrong, or I have misinterpreted. My problem is that I cannot seem to character by character index a string. Consider the snippet below

```
/* initializations */
char line[1000];
int i;

/* reading file */
fgets(line,1000,file);

/* the weird business */
printf("%s\n", line); 
i = 0;
while(i < sizeof(line)/sizeof(char))
{
    printf("%c",line[i]);
    i++;

}
printf("\n");
```

This snippet of code successfully reads a string from a file and then successfully prints that string. But when I attempt to print the individual characters with the while loop some nonsenical business involving square roots, smiley faces, and some characters from a language I don't even vaguely recall get printed out.

### So my deduction:

my `line` is not an array of the individual characters. Since if it was I should be able to just index through it and see them.

### My Question

1. What is actually going on here with my `line` variable
2. How do I index through the individual characters of a string?

Say I want to write (if the 7th character = `'h'` print 19) or something. How does one do individual character by character access with strings, if not by array indexing?

Comment: The first X characters of `line` (for some X) is what you read in (and `printf` printed). The remaining is...well, whatever was there before.

Comment: The smiley faces and other gibberish come from not properly checking the end of the string. `sizeof(line)` is 1000 and if your line only has 10 characters, the 990 other chars will likely contain gibberish or old line contents. The end of the string is signalled with the null char `'\0'`. That's also a problem with direct indexing: `line[10]` is not be part of the string when `line[8]` is the null char.

Comment: if you (a) check the result `fgets` for success (otherwise the content of `line` is indeterminate), (b) properly increment `i`with each iteration, and (c) stop when you reach the terminating nullchar that you *know* is there because you've done (a), your chances of success will increase substantially.

Comment: The problem is not that you can't print the string a character at a time. That works fine. The problem is that you don't know when to stop. Three possibilities: gets returns the length of the string it read. Strlen computes the length of a string. The string is terminated by a null byte.

Comment: Are the downvotes because of the title or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increment `i` to get the next character:

```
while(i < sizeof(line)/sizeof(char))
{
    printf("%c",line[i]);
    i++;  //  <-- add this
}
```

Also, `line[i]` is the correct way to handle strings character by character. So, if you want to access, say the 4th character, use `line[3]` (since it is 0-based indexing).

Also, another suggest: string length may be lesser than the length of line. So, instead use `strlen` to traverse till the end of string.

```
int len = strlen(line);

while(i < len)
{
    printf("%c",line[i]);
    i++;  //  <-- add this
}
```

`sizeof(char)` is not required as it is generally `1`.

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/hzffxg)

Comment: You should at least format code properly in an answer.

Comment: With any luck, the optimizer will realize you're never sending `line` anywhere that has potential side effects and *not* run that `strlen` with each iteration.

Comment: @karma_greek yes that is correct for the code i wrote here in the question. But it was present in my actual code. So that wasn't the issue.Let me try strlen and see how that goes :)

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Why did you put fake code in your question? That just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I didn't want to waste people's time putting 200 lines of stuff that isn't relevant to the problem, so I re-wrote the crux of exactly what my issue was. karma_geek was able to identify the problem and solve it with strlen, if I was in you shoes and someone else put the original code up, i for one would have yelled at the asker with the opposite complaint "can you just get to the point".

Answer (score 2):

> *1. What is actually going on here with my "line" variable*

Exactly what you've coded for. Nothing wrong.

> *2. How do I index through the individual characters of a string? Say I want to write (if the 7th character = 'h' print 19) or something. How does one do individual character by character access with strings, if not by array indexing?*

A pictorial representation of an array

[image: C Array]

Here, `num` is the array name, and `0`/`1`/`2` are the index. As you can see in the image, you need to *increment* the index by 1 to reach the next *element* in the array.

*FWIW, always remember, array index in `C` is `0` based, so the `7th` element will be `line[6]` and so on.*

Also, see the below points.

**Point 1**

Array indexes are not auto-incremented, you need to do that manually.

**Point 2**

`C` strings are *essentially* null terminated `char` arrays. You should stop printing at the terminating null of *string* to get the proper (*valid*) output.

**Point 3**

`fgets()` reads and stores the trailing newline. You probably want to exclude that while counting `strlen()`.

Modified code

```
i = 0;
int len = strlen(line) - 1;  // fgets() reads the trailing `\n`
while(i < len)
{
    printf("%c",line[i]);
    i++;  //increment the value of i to reach the next `char`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the End-Of-String `'\0'` character:

```
if(line[i] == 0) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

First an array in not a pointer.

```
char line[1000];
char *ix = line; /* ok ix[i] = line[i] for i in 0-999 */
printf("%d\n", sizeof(line));  /* gives 1000 */
printf("%d\n", sizeof(ix));  /* gives 4 on a 32 */
char line2[1000];
line2 = line;  /* ERROR line2 is not assignable */
```

Because a pointer is a *variable* that holds an address whereas an array is a contiguous memory zone.

A C string is a *null terminated array*. That means that by convention, a null character terminates a string, and `str*` functions follows that convention. The following declarations are the same :

```
char arr[4] = "abc"; /* 4 because of terminating null ! */
char arr[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 };
```

In you example to iterate a *string* you should use `strlen` which stops on a null (and so has sense when used on a pointer to a char array), instead of `sizeof` that gives you the *declared* size :

```
for(i=0; i<strlen(line); i++)    /* need #include <string.h> */
{
    printf("%c",line[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```